# Interpreting evaluationscheme from Recommenderlab in R

Tags: r, recommenderlab

I have created an evaluation scheme using the `recommenderlab` package with `binaryRatingMatrix`. How can I see which all users from the actual data are there in unknown test set?

```
scheme <- evaluationScheme(data = data1, method = "split", train = 0.9, given = 3)
```

where `data1` is `binaryRatingMatrix`. I would like to extract the list of users who are in the unknown set `getData(scheme, "unknown")`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This will print out the first column which is all the userIds.

```
getRatingMatrix(getData(scheme, "unknown")[,1])
```